# Super harmonic function

Tags: differential-equations, harmonic-functions

If $u>0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n\backslash\{0\}$ ($n\geq 2$) and  $-\Delta u>0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n\backslash\{0\}$, is it true that $\liminf_{|y|\rightarrow 0}u(y)>0$?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is true. Let me consider $v=-u$ for convenience,
so $v$ is subharmonic and negative. For a subharmonic function bounded from above, an isolated point is removable,
so v is actually subharmonic in $R^n$, if we define $v(0)=\limsup_{x\to 0} v(x).$ Now since it is strictly negative, we have by the average property
$$v(0)\leq c_n\int_{|x|=1} v(x)dx<0,$$
that is $\liminf_{x\to 0}u(x)>0.$

Reference for removable singularity:

Carleson, Lennart
Selected problems on exceptional sets. Zbl 0189.10903
Princeton, N.J.-Toronto, Ont.-London: D. Van Nostrand Co., Inc. V, 151 p. (1967).

Comment: Many thanks! I‘m not sure about the details of proofs in  the removable of the isolated point,  would you give more details. Thanks again!

Comment: By the way, is there such a function (strictly subharmonic and negative)? I cannot easily picture it.

Comment: @Malkoun   take $-r^{\alpha}$ for any $\alpha \in (2-n,0)$. (The subharmonic extension is allowed to take $-\infty$ as a value.)

Comment: Thank you @WillieWong. What about the case $n = 2$ please? Yes, I had forgotten that $-\infty$ was allowed... Thank you for that.

Comment: @Malkoun: when $n = 2$ Liouville's theorem states that any subharmonic function that is bounded above is constant.

Comment: Thank you @WillieWong (I was suspecting it was so for $n = 2$).

Comment: Non-constant subharonic functions bounded from above exist only in dimension $\geq 3$, but the removable singularity theorem holds in any dimension.